# Project Euler #17 in Java (off by 7)

Tags: java

So I wrote out the program in around 20 minutes and spending the last 40 racking my brain for why it's returning 21131 instead of 21124, which seems to be the right answer. I know it's not something wrong with the code (most likely) because it works for every number I tested, it's probably something stupid that I should have come up with a while ago.. here's the code:

```
public class Euler17 {
  public static final String[] numbers = new String[]{"", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
  public static final String[] tens = new String[]{"", "Ten ", "Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ", "Eighty ", "Ninety "};
  public static final String[] teens = new String[]{"Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"};
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a <= 1000; a++){
      sum+= toWords(a).replace(" ", "").length();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
  public static String toWords(int a){
    String w = "";
    // handle the 1000s ;)
    if (a / 1000 > 0){
      w+= numbers[((a % 10000) / 1000)] + " thousand ";
    }
    // handle the 100s
    if (a / 100 > 0){
      w+= numbers[((a % 1000) / 100)] + " hundred";
      if (a % 100 == 0){
        return w;
      }
      w+= " and ";
    }
    // handle the teens
    if ((a / 10) % 10 == 1){
      return w + teens[a % 10];
    }
    // handle the tens
    if (a / 10 > 0){
      w+= tens[((a % 100)/ 10)];
    }
    // handle the ones
    return w + numbers[a % 10];
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? What did that tell you?

Comment: Have you ever tried printing out the strings? `System.out.println(toWord(a));` - in the end it must be an error that occurs once and adds seven letters to the final result!

Comment: Yes I have, it doesn't print anything out of the ordinary. Maybe I can't count after all.. :D

Comment: Hint: look at the output of `System.out.println(toWord(1000));`? What should the output be?

Comment: OH MY GOD I CAN'T BELIEVE I MISSED THAT!!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is a bit late but I hope it can help you out.

I have just seen your question and said to myself lets have a go at it. anyway, I tried solving the issue you had, however, I couldn't keep up due to `variable` namings and other issues.

The solution I have implemented below uses a `HashMap` to solve the problem at hand. I have tried my best to at least provide comments within the code, so if you need any further explanation feel free to provide a comment.

**Global variables within class:**

```
private static Map<Integer,String> wordsCollection = new HashMap<>();
private static String andWord = "and", oneThousand = "onethousand";
```

**Method to solve the problem:**

```
private static void PE_Problem_17(){
        wordsCollection.put(1,"one"); wordsCollection.put(2,"two"); wordsCollection.put(3,"three");
        wordsCollection.put(4,"four"); wordsCollection.put(5,"five"); wordsCollection.put(6,"six");
        wordsCollection.put(7,"seven"); wordsCollection.put(8,"eight"); wordsCollection.put(9,"nine");
        wordsCollection.put(10,"ten"); wordsCollection.put(11,"eleven"); wordsCollection.put(12,"twelve");
        wordsCollection.put(13,"thirteen"); wordsCollection.put(14,"fourteen"); wordsCollection.put(15,"fifteen");
        wordsCollection.put(16,"sixteen"); wordsCollection.put(17,"seventeen"); wordsCollection.put(18,"eighteen");
        wordsCollection.put(19,"nineteen"); wordsCollection.put(20,"twenty"); wordsCollection.put(30,"thirty");
        wordsCollection.put(40,"forty"); wordsCollection.put(50,"fifty"); wordsCollection.put(60,"sixty");
        wordsCollection.put(70,"seventy"); wordsCollection.put(80,"eighty"); wordsCollection.put(90,"ninety");
        wordsCollection.put(100,"hundred");
        int countLetters = oneThousand.length();

        for (int number = 1; number <= 999; number++){
             if(number <= 20) {
                 countLetters += wordsCollection.get(number).length();  // handle from 1 to 20
                 continue;
             }

             if(number <= 99) {  // handle two digit numbers
                 countLetters += examineTwoDigits(number);
                 continue;
             }

             if(number <= 999){  // handle three digit numbers
                 countLetters += examineThreeDigits(number);
             }
        }

        System.out.println("Result = " + countLetters);  // print the result
}
```

**Helper method for two digit numbers:**

```
private static int examineTwoDigits(int number){  // helper method for two digit numbers
         int tempCount = 0;

         if(number == 0) return 0;

         if(number >= 1 && number <= 9){
             tempCount += wordsCollection.get(number).length(); // get length of number from hashMap
             return tempCount;
         }

         if(number % 10 == 0){
             tempCount += wordsCollection.get(number).length(); // get length of number from hashMap
             return tempCount;
         }

         for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
             if(i == number) {
                 tempCount += wordsCollection.get(number).length(); // get length of number from hashMap
                 return tempCount;
             }
         }

        int leftNumber = number / 10;
        String leftNumberString = Integer.toString(leftNumber) + "0";
        int rightNumber = number % 10;
        tempCount += wordsCollection.get(Integer.parseInt(leftNumberString)).length();
        tempCount += wordsCollection.get(rightNumber).length();
        return tempCount; // return the length of words count
}
```

**Helper method for three digit numbers:**

```
private static int examineThreeDigits(int number){ // helper method for 3 digits
        int tempCount = 0;
        int leftMostDigit = number / 100;  // get leftMost digit
        tempCount += wordsCollection.get(leftMostDigit).length() + wordsCollection.get(100).length();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(number));
        builder.deleteCharAt(0);
        if(Integer.parseInt(builder.substring(0,1)) != 0 || Integer.parseInt(builder.substring(1,2)) != 0){
            tempCount+= andWord.length();
        }
        tempCount += examineTwoDigits(Integer.parseInt(builder.toString()));
        return tempCount;
}
```